# API call returns promise object once executed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to return a simple string from my Laravel backend from a redux action, however on logging my returned value I get the following:

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

My action function is the following:

```
return function action(dispatch) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/test`).then(
            (response) => {
                const data = response.json();
                console.log(data);
                return dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTERED });
            },
            err => console.log(err)
        );
    }}
```

I know that I need to fulfill a promise in this scenario, however I thought I was achieving this by using .then() to handle anything returned once completed?

Comment: you need to await the promise, if this is a action creator you may need a thunk to do async/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `await` the promise and you may need to use a thunk, I have done it similar to this with action creators:

```
export function yourFunction (params) {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
      const options = { //some obj of headers, method, etc }
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, options)
      const resJson = await res.json()
      const { errors = [], data = {}, things = [] } = resJson
        dispatch({//dispatch something})
        return res
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } catch (errors) {
      return errors
    }
  }
}
```

check out the thunk middleware docs: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk